# NameError: name 'separate' is not defined on line 99

Tags: python, nameerror

This is my code that Im trying to recursively call the separate method but when run I keep getting an error when I try to call the separate method from within itself. Im still fairly new to Python and Im unsure about what is causing this error.

```
class operations():
  def separate(string):
    num1 = ""
    num2 = ""
    symbol = ""

    def hasSymbol(string):
      x=0
      for x in string:
        if(x == '&' or x == '^' or x == '|' or x == '<' or x == '>'):
          return True
      return False

    if(hasSymbol(num1) == True):
      separate(num1)
    if(hasSymbol(num2) == True):
      separate(num2)     //this is the line thats throwing the error

    return work(num1,symbol,num2)
```

Comment: You need to use `self.separate` since `separate` is defined under class `operations` as an instance method.

Comment: What is this supposed to do?  Why is this code in a class? If these are supposed to be static methods, you should be using the `staticmethod` decorator.

Comment: `class operations():` -> `class operations:`.

Comment: Class methods need a `self` parameter.